# How to fix the error "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed" when we already included the entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, edmx-designer

The answer looks like obvious, but, what I am facing is different.
I have 3 tables.. **Clients** related to **Users** that is related to **Messages**.
The idea is that I can have a message sent from somebody or nobody, but, always will have a destination;

```
[Message]
 * UserIdFrom (int) nullable; 
 * UserIdTo (int) not nullable;
```

Both fields are related to my table

```
[Users]
 * UserId (int);
 * ClientId (int) not null;
```

that is related with this another table

```
[Clients]
 * ClientId (Int);
 * CliName varchar;
```

My **EDMX** mapped the tables as following:

```
[Message]
 * UserIdFrom (int)  
 * UserIdTo (int) 
 + _Navigation properties_ + 
 * UserFrom (0..1) related to [Users] (on Navigation properties) 
 * UserTo   (1..*) related to [Users] (on Navigation properties)
```

and my Users mapped as:

```
[Users]
 * UserId (int)
 * ClientId (int)
 + _Navigation properties_ + 
 * Clients related to [Clients]
 * MessageFrom (0..1) related to [Message] (on Navigation properties) 
 * MessageTo   (1..*) related to [Message] (on Navigation properties)
```

And finally I have the Clients mapped:

```
[Clients]
 * ClientId (int)
 * ClientName (string)
 + _Navigation properties_ + 
 * Users related to [User]
```

**The problem:**

In my controller, I have the ActionResult that return the list of **Messages** that I (logged in) received from Someone (or nobody). So I have the following code:

```
return View(db.Users.Where(u => u.UsuEmail.Trim() == User.Identity.Name.Trim()).FirstOrDefault().MessageTo);
```

In my view, I try to show a text like:
**Daniel**(from) just sent a message to **Stackoverflow**(to)

For that, I use the following code (to show a list of messages):

```
@foreach (Messages message in Model)
{
   <p><strong>@message.UserFrom.Clients.ClientName</p>
}
```

The problem occours when I try to get informations about the Clients inside UserFrom, **however**, I can get informations about the UserTo;

So, I tried to use the **Include** function, trying to get information about who sent (MessageFrom). Example:

```
using (Entities db = new Entities()){    
  return View(db.Users.Include("MessageFrom").Where(u => u.UsuEmail.Trim() == User.Identity.Name.Trim()).FirstOrDefault().MessageTo);
}
```

or

```
using (Entities db = new Entities()){    
  return View(db.Users.Include("MessageFrom.Clients").Where(u => u.UsuEmail.Trim() == User.Identity.Name.Trim()).FirstOrDefault().MessageTo);
}
```

The most interesting thing is that I can get information about the addressee, but I can't get information from the sender.

I know how to use Include function (because I am using it in another situation), but, this time I don't know what I need to do.

Comment: The problem is that it is written in Portuguese